# C# Loop in KeyPressEventArgs

Tags: c#, keypress

I have the following event registered:

```
tb1.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(tb1KeyDown);
```

It does this:

```
public void tb1KeyDown(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
        {
            // Do my stuff
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

But, if I have entered the Enter key 2 times or more, my tb1KeyDown is in a loop for so often, that I have entered the Enter key.
What am I doing wrong here?

Greetz padde

Comment: I don’t understand your question. The KeyPressEvent will fire each time the Enter key is pressed. If you press enter twice your  function will fire twice.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "in a loop"? Is it an infinite loop and the program hangs, or is it simply called once for each enter press? Because that's the expected behavior.

Comment: If I press the key once, the event fires only once. But next time, I press the key, the event fires twice, then for the next single key press, it fires 3 times and so on.

Comment: @user2849380 What are you doing on //Do my stuff? Could you show your code also?

Comment: Where do you register your event handler? Is it possible, that you register it multiple times?

Comment: From the comments, one can think that event registration occurs more than once `tb1.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(tb1KeyDown);`

Comment: It was registered in a loop, so the handler was registered many times. Thank you.